# com.mysql.jdbc.Driverjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Netbeans 11.1

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, classnotfoundexception, mysql-connector

I have a problem with my code using Apache Netbeans 11.1

In this version of Netbeans I can't add a new library in my project so I set the mysql-connector-java-8.0.17 going to right-click on my project->properties->compile->manage java platform-> and set in source section the jar file.

I've already set new database connection by service window and it works, but when I execute the code of another project it can't connect to the mysql database.

This is my code:

```
 import java.sql.*;

 class esempio {
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
    private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String userName = "root";
    private String password = "password";
    private Connection con = null; 

    public void getConnection() { 
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            if(con == null) {         
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
            }
            System.out.print("Connection estd");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error : " + e.getMessage());     
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         esempio nuovo=new esempio();
         nuovo.getConnection();
     }//endmain    
 }
```

but the output says:

> Error : com.mysql.jdbc.Driverjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)     at
>   esempio.getConnection(esempio.java:28)    at
>   esempio.main(esempio.java:44)

Comment: Did you add the mysql,jar to your Libraries folder?